# Hibernate: evict() a persistent object while storing its changes

Tags: java, hibernate, session, memory-management

I have a persistent hibernate object I obtained using `session.save(object)`

I changed it since.

I want to execute `session.evict(object)` to save memory, as I am done with the object.

The documentation to `evict()` [here](http://ajava.org/online/hibernate3api/org/hibernate/Session.html#evict(java.lang.Object)) states that changes to the object will not be persisted. In other words - evict will cause me to lose changes I did to the object.

I could call `session.flush()` but that would flush all changes.

How can I persist changes made to a single persistent object before eviction?

Comment: Isn't it that changes to a persistent object can be saved anytime by Hibernate? I mean, regarding your argument against using flush(), maybe the changes that you do not want to save are already saved...

Comment: @SJuan76 Can I bet my production code on this assumption? The "anytime" worries me - they can be saved anytime, or at least at `session.flush()`. But if I evict in between... will the evict flush the object just before it gets evicted?

Comment: Why not use a statelesssession to begin with

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Call `session.save(object)` or `session.saveOrUpdate(object)`, then you can call evict on it if you must.  However, you must flush the session before doing this.  The session is designed to be a unit-of-work based interface, for good reason -- transactional semantics would be a disaster without this feature.  If you need to flush individual entities without flushing others that are part of the same session, you need to rethink your unit-of-work.

Comment: I thought the `save()` method is used solely for turning a transient object (is not managed by Hibernate) into a persistent one. And `saveOrUpdate()` will work either on transient or detached objects. However, my object is persistent, it was already created and previously saved by Hibernate, but it changed since.

Comment: Is this a batch operation? I.e. are you inserting a large number of rows? If so see http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#batch-inserts.  If not, why are you trying to do this?

Comment: Yes, it is a batch operation. I am updating a table to a newer version, changing rows that are modified, deleting unused rows, adding new ones. I guess your advice is still applicable for this operation, thank you!

Comment: I am accepting this answer for the clarifying comment, although the answer itself is not applicable in this context.

Answer (score 4):

Doing `session.evict(obj)` will remove the object instance from the session cache. Therefore if you are saving the object for the first time, you will have to explicitly commit via `session.save(obj)` before evicting the object from the cache. Subsequent update calls should follow through `session.saveOrUpdate(obj)` or `session.update(obj)` before calling evict to remove the loaded object from the cache.

In doing so means you will have to explicitly call `session.load(obj)` or `session.get(obj)` when you need the instance of the object back in the cache.

Comment: Why does the documentation say this? `save(Object)`: Persist the given ***transient*** instance, first assigning a generated identifier. (Or using the current value of the identifier property if the assigned generator is used.) This operation cascades to associated instances if the association is mapped with cascade="save-update". --- I already have an associated identifier, since the object was already `save`d before??

Comment: The Object is transient until serialized.

Comment: And my point is - I already serialized the object a long time ago. Since then, it has changed several times. And now I want to evict it. So, since it is no longer transient, `save` should not be applicable.

Comment: You do not need save(..) in your case, the example given is to provide an open clarity on how to evict, In your case you should update(..) and call evict to remove the loaded object from the cache as required.

Comment: The Hibernate documentation is horribly confusing, then. It states that `update` will re-attach a previously detached object. But my object is not detached, it is persistent. Should I submit a ticket asking for the javadoc to be changed to reflect what the function really does?

Comment: If I load an object, update it, and then evict it like this:

`Customer cust= session.load(33);
cust.setName("some Name");
session.update(cust);
session.evict(cust);`

This detach the object from the session. Calling 

`session.update(cust)` again will reference the object intance in memory, passing it reference again to the session to re-attach the object back to the session.

Comment: To understand this, you have to understand Hibernate Caching . See http://www.javabeat.net/articles/37-introduction-to-hibernate-caching-1.html

Answer (score -1):

Couldn't you manually save the object first via something like

```
session.saveOrUpdate(theObject);
session.evict(theObject);
```

Comment: My object is persistent, so according to the documentation, the `saveOrUpdate` should definitely not do a `save`. And http://ajava.org/online/hibernate3api/org/hibernate/Session.html#update(java.lang.Object) states it will throw an exception... Is the Hibernate documentation lying to me?