# Should I commit hibernate transaction before calling session.evict(obj)

Tags: java, transactions, hibernate-session

When should I commit a transaction in hibernate after saving it. Is it before or after I call session.evict(obj). Currently my code looks like this(only required parts).

```
Session session = connector.getSession();
Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
try {
        Criteria crit = session.createCriteria(ST_CODE_SETTINGS_STORE.class).add(Restrictions.eq("TYPE", "issueno"));
        List<ST_CODE_SETTINGS_STORE> ls = crit.list();
        if (ls.size() < 1) {
            session.save(st_code_settings_store);
            session.evict(st_code_settings_store);
            msg = "insert";
        } 
        else {
            Long Id = null;
            ST_CODE_SETTINGS_STORE st_code_settings_store1 = ls.get(0);
            Id = st_code_settings_store1.getCODE_ID();

            Object o = session.get(ST_CODE_SETTINGS_STORE.class, Id);
            ST_CODE_SETTINGS_STORE update = (ST_CODE_SETTINGS_STORE) o;
            session.update(update);
        }
        tx.commit();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        if (tx != null) {
            tx.rollback();
        }
        System.out.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
        connector.printStack(e);
        throw e;
    } finally {
        session.close();
    }
```

Sometimes if I commit after evicting, the data does not get saved in the database. Is it the right way to code??

Comment: refer [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6836326/4290096) and it's answers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The method evict() removes a single object from Session cache. **So
> before you call evict() the object should be there in the Session
> cache. Therefore if you save the object first time, you have to save
> the object via Session.save(object).** Subsequent update calls should
> follow through session.saveOrUpdate(object) or session.update(object)
> before calling evict() to remove the loaded object from the cache.([reference](http://www.roytuts.com/evict-method-in-hibernate/) )
>
> From [Hibernate Docs](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/transactions.html#transactions-basics)
>
> Ending a Session usually involves four distinct phases:
>
> - flush the session
> - commit the transaction
> - close the session
> - handle exceptions
>
> Do not use the anti-patterns session-per-user-session or
> session-per-application (there are, however, rare exceptions to this
> rule). Some of the following issues might also arise within the
> recommended patterns, so ensure that you understand the implications
> before making a design decision:
>
> - A Session is not thread-safe. Things that work concurrently, like HTTP
>   requests, session beans, or Swing workers, will cause race conditions
>   if a Session instance is shared. If you keep your Hibernate Session in
>   your HttpSession (this is discussed later in the chapter), you should
>   consider synchronizing access to your Http session. Otherwise, a user
>   that clicks reload fast enough can use the same Session in two
>   concurrently running threads.
> - An exception thrown by Hibernate means
>   you have to rollback your database transaction and close the Session
>   immediately (this is discussed in more detail later in the chapter).
>   If your Session is bound to the application, you have to stop the
>   application. Rolling back the database transaction does not put your
>   business objects back into the state they were at the start of the
>   transaction. This means that the database state and the business
>   objects will be out of sync. Usually this is not a problem, because
>   exceptions are not recoverable and you will have to start over after
>   rollback anyway.
> - The Session caches every object that is in a
>   persistent state (watched and checked for dirty state by Hibernate).
>   If you keep it open for a long time or simply load too much data, it
>   will grow endlessly until you get an OutOfMemoryException. **One
>   solution is to call clear() and evict() to manage the Session cache**,
>   but you should consider a Stored Procedure if you need mass data
>   operations.