# why hibernate update DB after evict

Tags: java, hibernate

I have two associated entites:

```
@Entity
@DynamicUpdate(true)
public class DreamTaskInfo {  
  private DreamInfo dreamInfo;  
  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "DREAM_INFO_ID", nullable = false)
  public DreamInfo getDreamInfo() {
      return dreamInfo;
  }  
 ...  
}  

@Entity
@DynamicUpdate(true)
public class DreamInfo {
    private Set<DreamTaskInfo> dreamTasks = new LinkedHashSet<>();
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "dreamInfo",cascade = CascadeType.ALL,   fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
   @OrderBy("remindTime")
   public Set<DreamTaskInfo> getDreamTasks() {
     return dreamTasks;
  }
  ...
}
```

I want to use a DreamTaskInfo data from DB for readonly use,so I do this:

```
DreamTaskInfo task = this.get(id);//query from db
getSession().evict(task);//getSession().contains(task)==false
```

But I find out Hibernate always execute a update sql on this task when flush.
At last,I use getSession().clear() instead of evict and it works.
Maybe eagerly fetch or association result in something in session?
Actually I don't modify anything manually and hibernate update automatically, so it has nothing to do with this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6836326/hibernate-evict-a-persistent-object-while-storing-its-changes).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hibernate: evict() a persistent object while storing its changes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6836326/hibernate-evict-a-persistent-object-while-storing-its-changes)

Comment: Can you post the update query along with its parameters. It's worth debugging to see why the update was generated.

Comment: @Vlad Mihalcea  ,actually it update every field of the record with value query from DB .

Answer (score 0):

you must flush the session before calling evict(). Then you won't see update query being run after evict().

Solution:

```
DreamTaskInfo task = this.get(id);//query from db
getSession().flush();// to make sure atomicity of session is maintained
getSession().evict(task);//getSession().contains(task)==false
```

There could have been some changes after you fetched the object from database, that is why hibernate will run Update query.

The session is designed to be a unit-of-work based interface, for good reason -- transactional semantics would be a disaster without this feature. If you need to flush individual entities without flushing others that are part of the same session, you need to rethink your unit-of-work.

Comment: I forget to mention that I have tried this way ,but not work.

Comment: "could have been some changes after you fetched the object from database,"  I have the same thought, but I use junit to test this method and not modify anything, so don't know how this happen exactly.

Comment: even if you have not modified any thing. You still need to call flush for the session. But as per your previous comment, I guess you have tried it. I will check again and get back to you.

Comment: @yuxh What's your solution

Comment: @ Gaurava ,I haven't figure out the reason ,use getSession().clear() for now.